# using a binary locale in Perl

Tags: perl, locale, collation

For some reason, for me, Perl is doing string comparisons where

```
if ("hãt" eq "hat")
```

evaluates to true. I think this is because I am using the wrong locale somewhere in my code but I'm not sure where (it's a big stack and I'm not sure how to determine the locale).

Is there a way that I can force a comparison using a binary collation or something similar, so that the above evaluates to false?

Comment: It's difficult to tell which part is a fact and which part is an assumption made by you. As the situation is presented, it's too outlandish too believe. Please give more hard facts and how the comparison looks in the actual code. Dump your strings with [Devel::Peek](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Peek) and add the output to your question. I suspect that you compare objects instead of string variables and `eq` is [overload](http://p3rl.org/overload)ed.

Comment: Perl source doesn't normally allow UTF-8 anyway, unless you are using the "use utf8;" pragma. And eq doesn't use the locale anyway, so that won't help. There is something else going on, and posting a larger fragment of code may help

Answer (score 0):

Perl defaults to the "C" locale unless a locale variable such as LC_ALL is set in your environment, in which cse you can force it like this:

```
use POSIX;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```